# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError executing .war generated by Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, noclassdeffounderror

I have a `.war` generated by Gradle, in Eclipse it doesn't show any problems and the project generates the `.war` without errors, but when I run the war I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/grizzly/http/servlet/ServletAdapter`:

```
INFO: Using classpath: file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-comet-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-http-servlet-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-http-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-utils-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-rcm-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/xmlparserv2-11.2.0.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-compat-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/javaee-web-api-7.0.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/poi-3.6-20091214.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/web-ajp-3.1.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/je-4.0.103.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-cometd-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/xdb-11.2.0.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-servlet-deployer-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-portunif-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/ucp.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc8.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-servlet-webserver-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/ojmisc.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/grizzly-framework-1.9.18-o.jar:file:/tmp/app_dir/apex/WEB-INF/lib/apex.jar

SEVERE: com/sun/grizzly/http/servlet/ServletAdapter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/grizzly/http/servlet/ServletAdapter
    at ____bootstrap.____Bootstrap.newServer(____Bootstrap.java:57)
    at ____bootstrap.____Bootstrap.startServer(____Bootstrap.java:125)
    at ____bootstrap.____Bootstrap._start(____Bootstrap.java:37)
    at ____bootstrap.____Bootstrap.start(____Bootstrap.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at ____embedded.____EntryPoint.invoke(____EntryPoint.java:273)
    at ____embedded.____EntryPoint.main(____EntryPoint.java:96)
```

Even though it seems I have this class available:
[image]

On build process I'm moving 2 directories from `src/main/java/` to the root of the `.war`, maybe this is causing the issue?
I have to move those because this war can be executed by command line.

My gradle.build:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin for API and implementation separation.
    id 'war'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {    
    implementation fileTree('libs')
    
    implementation 'com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-project:1.9.18b'
    implementation 'com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-servlet-deployer:1.9.18-o'
}

war {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': '____embedded.____EntryPoint'
        )
    }
    from 'build/classes/java/main/'
}

tasks.register('moveEntryPoint') {
    description 'Copies entrypoint to root dir.'
    doLast {
        ant.move file: "${buildDir}/classes/java/main/____embedded/",
                 todir: "${buildDir}/____embedded/"
    }
}
```

I run the war like this: `java -jar app.war params`

Code of where error happens:

```java
package ____bootstrap;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ____Bootstrap {
  // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
  protected Deployer newServer(Realm realm, String apexImages) {
    return new Deployer(apexImages, realm);
  }
  
  private void info(String text) {
    LOG.println("INFO: " + text);
  }
  
  private boolean isEmpty(char[] text) {
    boolean isWhitespace = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if (!Character.isWhitespace(text[i])) {
        isWhitespace = false;
        break;
      } 
    } 
    return isWhitespace;
  }
  
  private void patchXmlLibraries() {
    setIfAvailable("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
    setIfAvailable("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl");
    setIfAvailable("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
  }
  
  private String[] readCredentials(Console c, String role, String defaultName) {
    char[] first = new char[0];
    try {
      String username = c.readLine("Enter a username for the %s [%s]: ", new Object[] { role, defaultName }).trim();
      if (username.isEmpty())
        username = defaultName; 
      boolean match = false;
      boolean empty = true;
      while (!match) {
        first = c.readPassword("Enter a password for %s: ", new Object[] { username });
        if (isEmpty(first)) {
          c.format("Password must not be empty or whitespace.%n", new Object[0]);
          continue;
        } 
        char[] second = c.readPassword("Confirm password for %s: ", new Object[] { username });
        match = Arrays.equals(first, second);
        if (!match)
          c.format("Passwords do not match. Try Again.%n", new Object[0]); 
        Arrays.fill(second, ' ');
      } 
      return new String[] { username, new String(first) };
    } finally {
      Arrays.fill(first, ' ');
    } 
  }
  
  private Realm realm(File securityCredentials) {
    return FileCredentialsStore.realm("APEX Listener Manager", securityCredentials);
  }
  
  private void setIfAvailable(String property, String className) {
    try {
      Class.forName(className);
      System.setProperty(property, className);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
  }
  
  private void severe(Throwable t) {
    LOG.println("SEVERE: " + t.getMessage());
    t.printStackTrace(LOG);
  }
  
  private Deployer startServer(File war, Realm realm, Integer port, int ajpPort) {
    String apexImages = System.getProperty("apex.images");
    Deployer ws = newServer(realm, apexImages);
    if (war != null) {
      ws.setLocations(war.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
      ws.setLocations("");
    } 
    ws.setPort(port.intValue());
    if (ajpPort > 0)
      ws.setAJPPort(Integer.valueOf(ajpPort)); 
    return ws;
  }
  
  public static void start(File home, File war, Integer port, Integer ajpPort) throws Exception {
    ____Bootstrap instance = new ____Bootstrap();
    instance._start(home, war, port, ajpPort.intValue());
  }
}
```

It generates some classpath stuff here:

```
package ____embedded;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.jar.JarInputStream;

public class ____EntryPoint {
  private static final String APEX_ERASE_PROP = "apex.erase";
  
  static final String APEX_HOME_PROP = "apex.home";
  
  private static final String APEX_IMAGES_PROP = "apex.images";
  
  static final String APEX_PORT_PROP = "apex.port";
  
  static final String APEX_AJP_PORT_PROP = "apex.ajp";
  
  private static final String APEX_PROPERTIES = "apex.properties";
  
  private static final String BOOTSTRAP = "____bootstrap.____Bootstrap";
  
  private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
  
  private static final String DEFAULT_PORT = "8080";
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      if (args.length == 1 && args[0].equals("--help")) {
        usage(System.out);
      } else {
        File war = file(war());
        info("Starting: " + war.getAbsolutePath() + "\n See: 'java -jar " + war.getName() + " --help' for full range of configuration options");
        String portProp = System.getProperty("apex.port");
        if (portProp == null) {
          System.setProperty("apex.port", "8080");
          portProp = "8080";
        } 
        Integer port = Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(portProp));
        File home = DEFAULT_HOME;
        String apexHome = System.getProperty("apex.home");
        if (apexHome != null)
          home = new File(apexHome); 
        Properties props = apexProperties(home);
        if (!props.isEmpty())
          for (Object p : props.keySet()) {
            String prop = p.toString();
            String value = props.getProperty(prop);
            String existing = System.getProperty(prop);
            if (value != null && existing == null)
              System.setProperty(prop, value); 
          }  
        String ajpPortText = System.getProperty("apex.ajp");
        int ajpPort = -1;
        if (ajpPortText != null)
          ajpPort = Integer.parseInt(ajpPortText); 
        String erase = System.getProperty("apex.erase");
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(erase)) {
          info("Erasing: " + home.getAbsolutePath());
          delete(home);
        } 
        info("Extracting to: " + home.getAbsolutePath());
        File warFolder = new File(home, "apex");
        File warLib = new File(warFolder, "WEB-INF/lib");
        if (warFolder.exists())
          removeOldFiles(war, warFolder); 
        extractWar(war(), warFolder);
        apexImages(home);
        ClassLoader classloader = classloader(new File[] { new File(warFolder, PKG), warLib });
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classloader);
        invoke(classloader, "____bootstrap.____Bootstrap", "start", new Object[] { home, warFolder, port, Integer.valueOf(ajpPort) });
      } 
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      severe(t);
    } 
  }
  
  private static void apexImages(File home) throws IOException {
    String apexImages = System.getProperty("apex.images");
    Console c = System.console();
    File apexProperties = new File(home, "apex.properties");
    if (apexImages == null && !apexProperties.exists() && c != null) {
      boolean exists = false;
      while (!exists) {
        apexImages = c.readLine("Enter the path to the directory containing the APEX static resources\n\t  Example:  /Users/myuser/apex/images \n\t or press Enter to skip: ", new Object[0]).trim();
        if (apexImages.isEmpty()) {
          String again = c.readLine("Do you want to be prompted to specifiy this path next time? y/n [y]: ", new Object[0]).trim();
          if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(again)) {
            apexProperties.getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile().mkdirs();
            apexProperties.createNewFile();
          } 
          apexImages = null;
          break;
        } 
        File f = new File(apexImages);
        exists = f.exists();
        if (!exists)
          c.format("%s does not exist or is not accessible, please enter another path:%n", new Object[] { f.getAbsolutePath() }); 
      } 
    } 
    if (apexImages != null) {
      System.setProperty("apex.images", apexImages);
      Properties props = apexProperties(home);
      String existing = props.getProperty("apex.images");
      if (existing == null || !existing.equals(apexImages)) {
        props.setProperty("apex.images", apexImages);
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          out = new FileOutputStream(apexProperties);
          props.store(out, (String)null);
        } finally {
          close(new Closeable[] { out });
        } 
      } 
    } 
  }
  
  static Properties apexProperties(File home) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    File apexProperties = new File(home, "apex.properties");
    if (apexProperties.exists()) {
      InputStream propsStream = null;
      try {
        propsStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(apexProperties));
        props.load(propsStream);
      } finally {
        close(new Closeable[] { propsStream });
      } 
    } 
    return props;
  }
  
  private static ClassLoader classloader(File... folders) throws MalformedURLException {
    ClassLoader scope = new URLClassLoader(jars(folders));
    return scope;
  }
  
  private static void close(Closeable... items) {
    for (Closeable close : items) {
      if (close != null)
        try {
          close.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }  
    } 
  }
  
  private static final boolean delete(File file) {
    File failed = null;
    if (file.isDirectory())
      for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
        if (!delete(f)) {
          failed = f;
          break;
        } 
      }  
    if (failed == null && 
      !file.delete())
      failed = file; 
    return (failed == null);
  }
  
  private static long drain(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    if (is != null && os != null) {
      ReadableByteChannel source = Channels.newChannel(is);
      WritableByteChannel destination = Channels.newChannel(os);
      return drain(source, destination);
    } 
    return -1L;
  }
  
  private static long drain(ReadableByteChannel source, WritableByteChannel destination) throws IOException {
    long length = 0L;
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(65536);
    while (source.read(buffer) != -1) {
      ((Buffer) buffer).flip();
      length += buffer.limit();
      destination.write(buffer);
      buffer.compact();
    }
    ((Buffer) buffer).flip();
    while (buffer.hasRemaining())
      destination.write(buffer);
    return length;
  }
  
  private static boolean exists(JarFile jar, File root, File child) {
    String path = child.getAbsolutePath().substring(root.getAbsolutePath().length() + 1);
    return (jar.getEntry(path) != null);
  }
  
  private static void extract(InputStream in, File folder) throws IOException {
    JarInputStream jar = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
      jar = new JarInputStream(in);
      JarEntry entry;
      while ((entry = jar.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
        File target = new File(folder, entry.getName());
        if (isNewer(entry, target)) {
          if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            target.mkdirs();
            continue;
          } 
          target.getParentFile().mkdirs();
          out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(target));
          drain(jar, out);
          close(new Closeable[] { out });
          out = null;
        } 
      } 
    } finally {
      close(new Closeable[] { out, jar, in });
    } 
  }
  
  private static void extractWar(URL war, File folder) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
      in = war.openStream();
      extract(in, folder);
    } finally {
      close(new Closeable[] { in });
    } 
  }
  
  private static File file(URL url) {
    File file;
    try {
      file = new File(url.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      file = new File(url.getPath());
    } 
    return file;
  }
  
  private static void info(String text) {
    LOG.println("INFO: " + text);
  }
  
  private static void invoke(ClassLoader scope, String clazz, String method, Object... args) throws Exception {
    Class<?>[] types = new Class[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
      types[i] = args[i].getClass(); 
    Class<?> c = scope.loadClass(clazz);
    Method m = c.getMethod(method, types);
    m.invoke(null, args);
  }
  
  private static boolean isNewer(JarEntry entry, File target) {
    boolean exists = target.exists();
    long jarModified = entry.getTime();
    long targetModified = target.lastModified();
    return (!exists || jarModified == -1L || jarModified > targetModified);
  }
  
  private static URL[] jars(File... folders) throws MalformedURLException {
    StringBuilder classpath = new StringBuilder();
    List<URL> allUrls = new ArrayList<URL>();
    for (File folder : folders) {
      if (folder.exists()) {
        URL[] urls = jars(folder);
        if (urls.length == 0) {
          allUrls.add(folder.toURI().toURL());
        } else {
          for (URL url : urls) {
            allUrls.add(url);
            classpath.append(url.toExternalForm());
            classpath.append(":");
          } 
        } 
      } 
    } 
    info("Using classpath: " + classpath.toString());
    return allUrls.<URL>toArray(new URL[allUrls.size()]);
  }
  
  private static URL[] jars(File folder) throws MalformedURLException {
    File[] jars = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
          public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            name = name.toLowerCase();
            return (name.endsWith(".zip") || name.endsWith(".jar"));
          }
        });
    URL[] urls = new URL[(jars == null) ? 0 : jars.length];
    StringBuilder classpath = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      urls[i] = jars[i].toURI().toURL();
      classpath.append(urls[i].toExternalForm());
      if (i < jars.length)
        classpath.append(':'); 
    } 
    return urls;
  }
  
  private static void removeOldFiles(File war, File folder) throws IOException {
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(war);
    File root = folder;
    removeOldFiles(jar, root, folder);
  }
  
  private static void removeOldFiles(JarFile jar, File root, File folder) {
    File[] children = folder.listFiles();
    for (File child : children) {
      if (child.isDirectory())
        removeOldFiles(jar, root, child); 
      if (!exists(jar, root, child))
        child.delete(); 
    } 
  }
  
  private static void severe(Throwable t) {
    LOG.println("SEVERE: " + t.getMessage());
    t.printStackTrace(LOG);
  }
  
  private static void usage(PrintStream out) {
    out.println("java [options] -jar " + file(war()).getName() + " [--help]");
    out.println(" Options: ");
    out.println(" -Dapex.home=/path/to/apex      : Path to the folder used to store the");
    out.println("                                  web container runtime, defaults to:");
    out.println("                                  ${java.io.tmpdir}/apex ");
    out.println(" -Dapex.port=nnnn               : HTTP listen port, default 8080");
    out.println(" -Dapex.ajp=nnnn                : AJP (mod_jk) listen port, default none");
    out.println("                                  If an AJP Port is specified then HTTP access is disabled");
    out.println(" -Dapex.images=/images/location : Path to the folder containing static");
    out.println("                                  resources required by APEX");
    out.println(" -Dapex.erase=true              : Erase the contents of ${apex.home} ");
    out.println("                                  before launching");
    out.println(" --help                         : Print this usage message");
  }
  
  private static URL war() {
    return CLASS.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
  }
  
  private static final Class<____EntryPoint> CLASS = ____EntryPoint.class;
  
  private static final File DEFAULT_HOME = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/apex");
  
  private static final PrintStream LOG = System.out;
  
  private static final String PKG = CLASS.getPackage().getName();
  
  private static final String START = "start";
}
```

As I understand I get an error when it tries to call a method on a class that imports the Class it can't find.

Comment: `war` has different layout then ordinary jar and thus is using different classloading mechanism. So your question boils down to `____embedded.____EntryPoint` which you didn't show

Comment: @rkosegi Added Java class which originates the error.